# When to close a meta question?

Tags: discussion

Is it correct to close (*) a meta question simply because [the OP is not interested in the answer?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/define-what-an-unclear-question-is#comment26953_6906) Why don't you consider the utility of the post for other people (yourself)?

(*) example here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/define-what-an-unclear-question-is

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't you consider the utility of the post for other people (yourself)?

In this case, there isn't any long-term utility to care about. The question part of your post 
was:

> What is the difference between an unclear question and a question you are unable to answer?

Nobody in here closes questions because an answer is not immediately obvious. You can click on the unanswered tab of questions, and find enough examples to the same effect. [This comment](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/define-what-an-unclear-question-is#comment26960_6906) best clarifies the stance people have regarding the question which got closed.

Now, the rest of that meta post, and the comments below that post, are just an extended rant. We get it, everybody feels upset when their question gets closed, and having been on this site for more than an year, I have seen many of them resort to angry ranting in chat or meta. When you are in chat, you can still get away with it, but content-less rants in meta, and especially those accompanied by statements like:

> I'm not really interested in your answer. I simply think that it would be [in principle, theoretically] useful for you to write down an answer [of course you will sort of "copy and paste" another wrong answer, so it won't be useful at all].

really provide no lasting retention value.

Relax. It is an internet community of anonymous strangers, and you are an anonymous user too. A question got closed, ego felt bruised probably, but its no big deal. You will get over it in a day or too. But if you keep spamming meta with more and more content-less rants, you potentially risk being deemed an angry spammer, and would perhaps eventually face a *cool-down suspension*.

I advise you to relax, and take some time off. A question by an anonymous user, getting closed, is really no big deal. But making a mess out of it, is!

Comment: I hope you don't get offended if I say that your answer is similar to the one of an idiot - and of course is clear that I'm not saying and I don't want to say that you are an idiot. But let me better explain my comment. You write "In this case, there isn't any long-term utility to care about." Ok, now we have to analyse the starting point "In this case". It is the case of closing a meta question. Well, now, what does it prevent? It prevents answering that question. So, where could there be a potentially lost utility if not in those answers? You imply that you are unable to answer well.

Comment: @giulio_hep - yes, on this site, we have people of average abilities who don't stack up to your standards of brilliance. I apologize for my low IQ. End of conversation.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of this specific question: The definition of what is meant by an "unclear" question is quite explicitly laid out in many places around the meta site and in the banner that appears on a question closed as such. This means that the only reason to discuss what it means would be context specific; we would discuss it only in terms of the linked question and only clarify it insofar as the OP or whoever is confused requires.

Given that the OP of the meta post indicated quite clearly that they are not actually interested in any clarifying answer, there is not much to be done on this post. In its current form, the only way to answer the question would be with a general outline of what makes a question unclear enough to close. There are so many meta posts about this already and plenty of meta posts on the mother meta site that address what makes a question unclear.

The feedback on the closed question itself reads:

> *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.*

What could be more clear? That indicates that, regardless what the OP may think, at least 5 3k+ users (or a combination of < 5 3k+ users and 1 mod) thought the wording of the question was sufficiently unclear that they couldn't be sure what it asked and how an answer to it should be formed. That is the general case on what separates a clear question from an unclear one.

The only thing left after that is to ask what specifically makes a given question unclear, which the OP of this meta post explicitly indicates is not what they are interested in. That means there really isn't anything being asked by the post. At best, this becomes a duplicate of any number of "What does unclear mean for a question?" posts. But this question also requests us to give the distinction between closing as "unclear" and closing as "unable to answer". Since there is no such thing or any occurrences of a closing as "unable to answer", that makes this meta post, at worst, itself unclear (which would be a tad ironic).

I personally would have found a nice duplicate for it rather than closing it as off-topic, but the question was closed already. I'm not going to have it reopened just so I can close it properly.

Answer (score 1):

In an earlier age of the this site the moderators allowed certain parties to use meta questions as a forum for sly insinuations---one that they knew we wouldn't answer because of the moderator agreement---and other forms of character assassination.

Frankly I got sick of it, so I'm not very bothered that you were prevented from launching a rant with no actual purpose beyond venting your pique. Sorry, but that is how it is.

---

As to what defines an unclear question, that is mind bogglingly simple:

> If a quorum of users vote to close it as unclear and no quorum votes to re-open it then it qualifies as unclear for the purposes of closing.

That's the whole shebang because this is a crowd sourced platform.